# Angular compiler ngc stuck without any error output

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

## Description

Hello
I am testing angular-universal app. I did prove of concept in little project but when I am testing same in my main project it stuck in middle of compilation.

So I have 2 main stages. Build and Compile.
For build I use following command:

```
ng build --prod
```

Everything is fine after this processes.

To compile my project I use following command:

```
ngc
```

And console just stuck here:

```
> myProject@0.0.5 ngc E:\WorkSpase\myProject\browser
> ngc
```

Nothing happening after that.

## What I have tried already

1.TypeScript compilation

```
tsc
```

Result: I have same stuck

2.Add debug option to tsconfig.json with hope that I will see some additional log output, but no.

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "debug": true,
   "genDir": "./target/classes/ngfactory",
   "entryModule": "./src/app/components/app.module#AppModule"
 }
```

Result: Nothing new.

### Summary:

So I cant move forward because I just don't know the reason of that stuck.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why do you use `ngc`? I dont think you really need that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `ngc` at all. When I was struggling with angular universal, this seed project really helped: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

It has 2 versions, one for manual webpack configuration, one for angular cli project.

Overall, for CLI project you need to:

1. Create `AppServerModule`, that will import `ServerModule` from `@angular/platform-server`.
2. Create `main.server.ts` file that will export `AppServerModule`.
3. Create `server.ts` file - that one will be used for bootstrapping server side. The file should look like this: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/cli/server.ts
4. Create `tsconfig.server.json` file that will have typescript configuration for server side - here you need to specify that you want `commonjs` modules as output.
5. Add second app to your `.angular-cli.json` file (`apps` array), that will have different `outDir` folder - this one will be used for server side rendering. In this app you will also link the `main.server.ts` file as `main` and `tsconfig.server.json` file as `tsconfig`.
6. Then there is one more thing you need to do, because of one issue with angular cli (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200) - create `webpack.server.config.js` file that you will use to recompile server side code. The file can look like this: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/cli/webpack.server.config.js.
7. Now you should be ready to go, you need to build both cli apps with `ng build && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false`.
8. After building, run the webpack with your server side config: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js` (you need to have `webpack` installed globally for this, or adjust the path to its binary).
9. And finally start the node server that with `node dist/server`.

Minimal `AppServerModule` should look like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // The AppServerModule should import your AppModule followed
        // by the ServerModule from @angular/platform-server.
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ],
    // Since the bootstrapped component is not inherited from your
    // imported AppModule, it needs to be repeated here.
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

`tsconfig.server.json` should look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // Set the module format to "commonjs":
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  // Add "angularCompilerOptions" with the AppServerModule you wrote
  // set as the "entryModule".
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I don't have a problem with my test app. I works fine. But when I add all libraries that are used in my main project - It stuck. But i don't know why and i cant see any error log. So I cant understand what is the problem.

Comment: Well first of all, I would suggest to update your angular to latest version, as this universal thing is pretty cutting edge technology, that is still under development. The way I described in my answer is the way how you should do it with the current (angular 4.4) version, I don't know the other way that you are trying to use...

Comment: Anyway, if it breaks when you add some third party dependency, its usually because it touches `window` or `document` directly - you do not have access to those on server side. You can walk around this by adding if conditions and do those things only in the browser (see this for more info https://github.com/angular/universal#universal-gotchas)

Comment: But as I said, I do not believe you need that `ngc` at all, that is not the way how you should do it (with current version of angular). `ngc` is for Ahead of Time compilition. With latest angular, this is already done with the `--prod` flag when building.

Comment: Here is example project and tutorial that use ngc:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)

It works and made much more simply then angular universal starter.

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help me.
And yea I understand that third party libs can be made with bugs for server side rendering. But main weird thing is that I cant see any error log when compiling app. And I think that any way in angular-universal starter project somewhere in build cycle there is same compilation stage anyway.

Comment: Well it might look like its complicated, but it has one big advantage - you still have your SPA ready to go, so you can use it for fast development and leave the SSR only for staging/production environments.

Comment: Btw if you take a look at the article you posted, there is a note at the bottom `This tutorial is largely based on the example located here`. When you go there, you will see big warning at the top: `DEPRECATED!!!` :] The way I described is really the way how you should do it with current version. I understand that you would rather fix what you have now, than updating, but as I said earlier, I believe that the update is worth it, as angular/universal is still cutting edge tech that changes a lot in these days...